# Add a xib file to UITableView as a header within the UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a subclass of `UITableViewController`, and my table is good and ready.
my problem is, I want to add a custom `UIView` as the header of the table. so I created an empty xib file "HeaderView.xib" and add my views in it (one `UIView` and 2 `UIButton`) and added the class of the UITableViewController as the file owner, and connected my two buttons to the class:

```
- (IBAction)addNewItem:(id)sender
{

}

- (IBAction)toggleEdittingMode:(id)sender
{

}
```

in a class extension I added a property of type UIView:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *headerView;
```

then I overridden the getter method:

```
- (UIView *)headerView
{
    if (_headerView) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderView"
                                      owner:self
                                    options:nil];
    }
    return _headerView;
}
```

and in viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.headerView;
```

I don't know if this is the right approach as I cannot see my header when I run the app

thanks for your help

Comment: How can I do that? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have implemented the getter for `headerView` will always return `nil`. Something like this should behave more appropriately:

```
- (UIView *)headerView {
    if (!_headerView) {
        _headerView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderView" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;
    }
    return _headerView;
}
```

You need to actually set the `_headerView` to the first object in the array of views returned from `loadNibNamed`.